# Bootstrap Jquery Select input can i include custom div as a option for the dropdown

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap JQuery select , converts Select into a drop-down.

Can I include a custom div in the option so that upon a particular option clicked this div has to be loaded?

The code I am trying to include is the following.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu customDropdown">
    <div class="tp-12">
        Number of days <input type="text" class="input-md fw-w-50 fw-ml-5 fw-border-danger" value="60" data-toggle="uitooltip" data-placement="right" data-classes="ui-tooltip-sm" title="Field should be between 1 to 360 " />
    </div>
    <div class="border border-top ">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-left-space">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: "*this div has to be loaded"* - loaded where?  Your question makes no sense.  Sounds like you want a dialog/modal - see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/